# Pegando dados no banco de dados do entity framework(pegando os cupons de desconto)

Tags: c#

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como posso fazer por ajax para ele percorrer meu banco e ver e existe um código de aplicar desconto:

**DAO:**

```
public void Adiciona(Desconto desconto)
    {
        using (var context = new LojaContext())
        {
            context.Descontos.Add(desconto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public IList<Desconto> Lista()
    {
        using (var contexto = new LojaContext())
        {
            return contexto.Descontos.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Atualiza(Desconto desconto)
    {
        using (var contexto = new LojaContext())
        {
            contexto.Descontos.Update(desconto);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public Desconto BuscaPorId(int id)
    {
        using (var contexto = new LojaContext())
        {
            return contexto.Descontos.Find(id);
        }
    }
```

Minha tabela no banco de dados mostra o ID, PORCENTAGEM DE DESCONTO E O CÓDIGO DO DESCONTO.

Meu controller do carrinho onde tem o botão de colocar o código e aplicar o desconto:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
    {
        var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();


        var produto = new ProdutosDAO().BuscaPorId(id);

        foreach (var item in carrinho.ItensPedido)
        {
            if (item.Produto.Id == produto.Id)
            {
                item.Quantidade++;
                Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
                return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
            }
        }
        carrinho.AdicionaProduto(produto);
        Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
    }
    public ActionResult ExcluiProdutoCarrinho(int id)
    {
        var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();
        var produto = new ProdutosDAO().BuscaPorId(id);
        carrinho.RemoverProduto(produto.Id);
        Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
    }
    public ActionResult Carrinho()
    {
        Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();
        var produtos = carrinho.ItensPedido;
        ViewBag.Produtos = produtos;
        return View(carrinho);
    }

    //public ActionResult AdicionarDesconto(int id)
    //{
    //    if ()
    //}
```

Meu botão:

                    Aplicar desconto

Eu preciso saber como adicionar esses cupons de desconto e fazer um ajax para pegar eles no banco e poder utilizar no botão de desconto.

Comment: Mas como é a lógica na aplicação? Na view o usuário que entra com um código de desconto? Ou isso vai ser verificado em alguma outra ação? Da forma que explicou e sem sua view não conseguiremos ajudar muito.

Comment: Coloque o código que você começou a fazer a chamada ajax com base no que você já pesquisou e tentou.

Answer (score 0):

Meu ajax

```
    function aplicaDesconto() {
        var codigo = $("#codDesconto").val();
        var total = @total;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'AplicaDesconto',
            data: {
                codigo
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.sucesso == true) {
                    $(".totalCarrinhoCompra").text(@total  * 0.20);

                    var DESCONTO10 = @total  * 0.10;
                    var DESCONTO20 = @total  * 0.20;
                    var DESCONTO30 = @total  * 0.30;
                    var DESCONTO40 = @total  * 0.40;
                    var DESCONTO50 = @total  * 0.50;
                    var DESCONTO60 = @total  * 0.60;
                    var DESCONTO70 = @total  * 0.70;
                    var DESCONTO80 = @total  * 0.80;
                    var DESCONTO90 = @total  * 0.90;


                } else {

                }

            }

        })
    }
```

Meu botão:

// 
                    Aplicar desconto
              // >

Não está pegando os itens e aplicando o desconto..

Erros:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Uncaught ReferenceError: aplicaDesconto is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick